# How add subcategory in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, model, controller

i need add subcategory after category in this code:
Help pls

Controller:

```
public function find_diagnoz() {
        $key = $this->input->get('key');
        $result = $this->Diagnoz_model->find_diagnoz($key);
        
        foreach ($result as $key => $res) {
            
            /* Категория */ 
            $this_cat = $this->Diagnoz_model->get_categories($res['id']);
            if (!$this_cat) {
                
                $rec->cat = false;
                continue;
                
            }
            
            $result[$key]['cat'] = $this_cat['names'];
            
        }
        
        $html = '';
        foreach ($result as $res) {
            
            $html .= '<li>';
            
            $html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$res['id'].'" data-code="'.md5($res['id'].$res['texts']).'" data-title="'.$res['texts'].'" class="select_td">';
            
            $html .= '<p>'.$res['texts'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p>Из категории: '.$res['cat'].'</p>';

            $html .= '</a>';
            
            $html .= '</li>';
            
        }
        
        die(json_encode(array('html' => $html)));
        
    }
```

Model
For get category name:

```
public function get_category($id) {
    
    $this_category = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from('zaloby')
                            ->where('id = '.$id)
                            ->get()->result_array();

    if (!isset($this_category[0])) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $this_category[0];
    
}
```

For get result by key:

```
public function find_diagnoz($key) {
    
    $res = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('zaloby')
                    ->like('names', $key)
                    ->get()->result_array();
                    
    return $res;
    
}
```

Mysql table have structure:

```
id parid names text
1   0    name1  desc1
2   1    name2  desc2
3   2    name3  desc3
4   2    name4  desc4
```

When I search result now, my result:
Name2
In category: Name2

I need result with subcategory:
Name2
In category: Name1 / Name2

Thx, sorry for my bad english.